# SQL `lead()` equivalent in R

Tags: r

I want to make something like `LEAD(mes) OVER(PARTITION BY CODIGO_CLIENTE ORDER BY mes) mes_2` in R, but I dont know a similar function.

I have no clue how to work it out.

Comment: You could take a look at the dplyr package. It contains ``lead/lag`` functions.

Answer (score 2):

Since you shared no data and desired output, here is an example with `lead()` from the `dplyr` package. The example is from the **Help** page of `lead()`. This can give you a good idea of what you can do with this function.

```
df <- data.frame(year = 2000:2005, value = (0:5) ^ 2)
scrambled <- df[sample(nrow(df)), ]

  year value
1 2000     0
5 2004    16
3 2002     4
4 2003     9
2 2001     1
6 2005    25

right <- mutate(scrambled, `next` = lead(value, order_by = year))
arrange(right, year)

  year value next
1 2000     0    1
2 2001     1    4
3 2002     4    9
4 2003     9   16
5 2004    16   25
6 2005    25   NA
```

Since you're new to R I suggest you read a bit on the dplyr package. Also, to make it easier for the people trying to help you, please provide more details next time!